# Logrotate lastaction script not working

Tags: shell, debian, logrotate

I have a lastaction script I'm trying to run in my "log" folder, as I want to move all files and folders in the log folder inside the log/archive folder. So I simply added

```
mv log/* log/archive/2014
```

Obviously enough, I get an error saying archive folder cannot be moved to a subdirectory of itself, so I tried adding the extra parameter to the move command to move everything except the archive folder.

```
mv !(archive) log/* log/archive/2014
```

This exact command, if executed from cli, works just fine, but when added inside the lastaction/endscript block, it throws the following message

> logrotate_script: 2: logrotate_script: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Anybody has any clue on why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `bash` as your shell. You also have the `extglob` setting enabled.

When logrotate is executing that shell script one or the other of those is not true.

Also that `mv` command looks odd to me. If `archive` is under log then I don't see why `!(archive)` doesn't have `log/` as a prefix. Also the `log/*` should still be matching `log/archive` regardless of the `extglob` glob before it. (That is I would think you wanted `mv log/!(archive) log/archive/2014`, assuming you don't feel like just ignoring the warning from `mv` in the first place.)

Comment: The syntax (mv log/!(archive)) does not work from cli for me, as it throws "bash: !: event not found"

Comment: `mv !(archive)` worked (as in your OP) but `mv log/!(archive)` does not? Do you have `extglob` enabled? In your shell if the former works the latter should. In the logrotate script you need to use bash and ensure `extglob` is enabled but history expansion should not be a problem since it should be disabled in scripts by default.